# I would like to make an EditFor textbox accept numbers only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

This is my ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.ValidationsResources),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
[Range(0, 9999, 
       ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationsResources),
       ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomenteNumeros")]
public Int16 Quantidade { get; set;}
```

This is my View:

```
 <label class="Quantidade">
   <span>Quantidade</span>
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantidade)
 </label>
```

But I want to block all words in this editor and allow only numbers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression, e.g.

```
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Count must be a natural number")]
public int Count { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need javascript for this. There are many [jQuery plugins](http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/) that could help you implement this.