# How to allow only numbers in textbox in mvc4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 text box which takes values postal code & mobile number & residential number.
I got the solution for allowing only number in text box using jquery from Bellow post.

[I would like to make an EditFor textbox accept numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310796/i-would-like-to-make-an-editfor-textbox-accept-numbers-only)

but can we do this using data annotations as I am using MVC4 razor ?

Comment: you cannot do this because data annotations are called when you submit your form, not when you enter data to your textboxes

Comment: while that is true, you can use the HTML5 input types validation rules (where supported by browser). works in this question scenario.

Comment: Use jQuery with a css class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Int or Number DataType for DataAnnotation validation attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816822/int-or-number-datatype-for-dataannotation-validation-attribute)

Comment: @KarthikChintala That is incorrect. The data annotations are also used to when rendering the form, to determine client side jQuery validations and input types for various fields.

Answer (score 113):

i was just playing around with HTML5 input type=number. while its not supported by all browsers I expect it is the way going forward to handle type specific handling (number for ex). pretty simple to do with razor (ex is VB)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Port, New With {.type = "number"})
```

and thanks to Lee Richardson, the c# way

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Port, new { @type = "number" })
```

beyond the scope of the question but you could do this same approach for any html5 input type

Comment: aka @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Port, new { @type = "number" })

Comment: You can also input "-" and "+" that are characters not number.

Comment: This is at least partially supported in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) except Opera Mini.

Comment: Besides "-" and "+" characters you can input "e" character. I used Data Annotation + regex as pointed by Donal Lafferty in his answer.

Answer (score 67):

Use a regular expression, e.g.

```
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Count must be a natural number")]
public int Count { get; set; }
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 58):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PositiveNumber, 
                      new { @type = "number", @class = "span4", @min = "0" })
```

in MVC 5 with Razor you can add any html input attribute in the anonymous object as per above example to allow only positive numbers into the input field.

Comment: Pretty neat solution for front end Validation. Thanks to save my time @realaValoro :-)

Comment: Where does the span4-class come from?

Comment: it's just a sample on how to specify any css class for a text box.

Answer (score 16):

in textbox write this code `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"`
and function for this is just below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: javascript event is not defined firefox

Comment: This wont work on a lot of smartphones as the keypress event is not available on all mobiles.

Comment: it was answered for MVC4 razr

Answer (score 9):

Please use the `DataType` attribute. This will accept negative values so the regular expression below will avoid this:

```
   [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber,ErrorMessage="Not a number")]
   [Display(Name = "Oxygen")]
   [RegularExpression( @"^\d+$")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required")]
   [Range(0,30,ErrorMessage="Please use values between 0 to 30")]
    public int Oxygen { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me :

```
<input type="text" class="numericOnly" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch">
```

Javacript:

```
//Allow users to enter numbers only
$(".numericOnly").bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '9' || e.keyCode == '16') {
        return;
    }
    var code;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    if (e.which == 46)
        return false;
    if (code == 8 || code == 46)
        return true;
    if (code < 48 || code > 57)
        return false;
});

//Disable paste
$(".numericOnly").bind("paste", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".numericOnly").bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != '0') {
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "")
        $(this).val(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: This wont work on a lot of smartphones as the keypress event is not available on all mobiles.

Answer (score 8):

Use this function in your script and put a span near textbox to show the error message

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".digit").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            $("#errormsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
        }
    });
});

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.company.ContactNumber, new { @class = "digit" })
<span id="errormsg"></span>
```

Comment: upvoted for simple solution .I don't know why they didn't marked it as answer working like charm

Comment: This wont work on a lot of smartphones as the keypress event is not available on all mobiles.

Answer (score 4):

for decimal values greater than zero, HTML5 works as follows:

```
<input id="txtMyDecimal" min="0" step="any" type="number">
```

Comment: And how do you do this with the HTMLhelper in razor?

Comment: I attempted to use Razor, but after searching for ages, I couldn't find a solution that was this clean.

Answer (score 3):

`can we do this using data annotations as I am using MVC4 razor ?`

No, as I understand your question, unobtrusive validation will only show erorrs. The simplest way is use jquery plugin:

[Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the javascript that will allows you to enter only numbers.

Subscribe to `onkeypress` event for textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Phone,new { @onkeypress="OnlyNumeric(this);"})
```

Here is the javascript for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnlyNumeric(e) {
            if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46 || e.which == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Not all Code paths return a value,  and it doesn't work for me

Comment: This wont work on a lot of smartphones as the keypress event is not available on all mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [Integer] data annotation (If you use the DataAnnotationsExtensions http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) . However, this wil only check if the value is an integer, nót if it is filled in (So you may also need the [Required] attribute).

If you enable Unobtrusive Validation it will validate it clientside, but you should also use Modelstate.Valid in your POST action to decline it in case people have Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

`DataType` has a second constructor that takes a string. However, internally, this is actually the same as using the `UIHint` attribute.

Adding a new core DataType is not possible since the `DataType` enumeration is part of the .NET framework. The closest thing you can do is to create a new class that inherits from the `DataTypeAttribute`. Then you can add a new constructor with your own `DataType` enumeration.

```
public NewDataTypeAttribute(DataType dataType) : base(dataType)
 { }

public NewDataTypeAttribute(NewDataType newDataType) : base (newDataType.ToString();
```

You can also go through [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-advantages-of-custom-attributes-in-your-c-applications/6175490) link. But I will recommend you using Jquery for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following....

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {onkeydown="return ValidateNumber(event);" })%>
  <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ValidateNumber(e) {
       var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
       var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
       if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   };
```

Comment: This wont work on a lot of smartphones as the keypress event is not available on all mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MobileNo, new { @class = "digit" , @maxlength = "10"})

@section Scripts 
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(".digit").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
            {
                $("#errormsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
            }
         });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<input type="number" @bind="Quantity" class="txt2" />

Use the type="number"

Answer (score -1):

```
function NumValidate(e) {
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert('Only Number ');
        return false;
    }    return true;
}  function NumValidateWithDecimal(e) {

var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;

if (!(charCode == 8 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 110 || charCode == 13 || charCode == 9) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    alert('Only Number With desimal e.g.: 0.0');
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
} } function onlyAlphabets(e) {
try {
    if (window.event) {
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
        var charCode = e.which;
    }
    else { return true; }

    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode == 46) || (charCode == 32))
        return true;
    else
        alert("Only text And White Space And . Allow");
    return false;

}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
}} function checkAlphaNumeric(e) {

if (window.event) {
    var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
}
else if (e) {
    var charCode = e.which;
}
else { return true; }

if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode == 32) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert('Only Text And Number');
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: how about a little description of your solution?

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)