# How to return validate key with some Condition In Razor by jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I need to check some condition and based on that run a jQuery function on keypress for validate key.

I have 3 types for validate.

- text
- Integer, decimal or double
- formula and I want get number and some formula sign for example gets only (*-/+) and number.

How can I do it ? Any help ?

```
@for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.ParamStructList.Count ; i++)
{
   @Html.TextBox("ParamStructList["+i+"].value",Model.ParamItemValueList[i].Value,new{onkeypress=""})
}
```

Comment: Read up on unobtrusive validation: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/

Comment: @zaitsman ur answer not related to my question ,I dont want define attribute for fields in viewmodel.I want check condition in view .

Comment: if you read the article you will see that is EXACTLY what unobtrusive validation gives you.

Comment: In additional,I check condtion by an enum type.

Comment: Of course you can roll with any kind of stuff you want :) the unobtrusive validation is a fairly standard, cheap and no effort required feature provided by Microsoft for a few years. If you prefer to roll your own framework, you're welcome to. I suggest it would be hard to find someone to write it for you, though, as the question as you've asked it is ways too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataType` and `RegularExpression` attribues in model.(see [this](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727979/how-to-allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-in-mvc4-razor))